# In-line comments in align?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

Is there a way to insert comments at the end of a line, within a block of TeX? For example, something like the following

```
$$\begin{align} 
&(B \cap A) = (C \cap A) \\    'given 
&(B \cap A) \cup (B  \cap \overline{A}) = (C \cap A) \cup (C  \cap \overline{A}) \\ 'substitution and distributive law \end{align}$$
&B = C
```

where `'` would indicate a comment. It would be handy for justifying certain steps when writing proofs.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Best pattern for adding commentary in `align` environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/38168/5764)

Comment: As reference, read [Why is `\[` …`\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27283/15925